# How to transfer transaction and send balance on public blockchain using web3py api?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py

I have followed tutorial and setup private Blockchain using geth:

https://medium.com/infrageth/practical-steps-for-go-ethereum-setup-27b8d64903fc

I have used

> web3py

python library for creating web services
I have created own

> genesis.json

- So my question is we are giving local address and assigning some
  balances so what are these balances
- Is it that only through local    address we can send transaction
  because i have generated address
- I have tried to send transaction using web3 api and also i am not
  able to get balance even i have transferred eth i can see balance in

> https://etherscan.io/

but not through api.
so i am confused how is it working any help will be greatly appreciated

my send transaction code is :

```
        send_transaction = my_provider.eth.sendTransaction(
            {'from': checksum_sendaddress, 'to': checksum_recvaddress, 'value': amt})
```

My code is executed successfully and it will generate  txhash successfully but when  I am adding  this hash to site 
https://etherscan.io/
the transaction is not shown

Comment: Hi! Web3.py is a library for Python programmers. Can you be more specific what have you tried (show us the code you have written) and then more specific how it failed (was the result incorrect, was there an error).

Comment: I have used below code to send transaction

Comment: In the question you mention a private blockchain. EtherScan service is for public Ethereum blockchain. EtherScan cannot show transactions for your private chain. Was this your question?

Comment: If you wish to use EtherScan service to check your transactions, I suggest doing testing and prototying using Kovan or Goerli test networks where you can get free test ETH.

Comment: In the question you mention a private blockchain. EtherScan service is for public Ethereum blockchain. EtherScan cannot show transactions for your private chain. Was this your question? yes exactly @MikkoOhtamaa

Comment: i am trying to create web service for ethereum... but i am not understanding that i am generating address and it is shown on etherscan but now i want to perform transaction and i want it to be shown publicly and to transfer real ethereum so could it be possible and how can do it for public blockchain@MikkoOhtamaa

Comment: Same same, just connect to a public Ethereum network. I suggest service infura.io to get an access to mainnet and testnet nodes.

Comment: So, would i able to transfer real eth and perform transaction using infura api @Mikko Ohtamaa

Comment: And would i able to see it in etherscan

Comment: Yes. Testnet infrastructure is shared and global.

Comment: for sending transaction it is neccessary to deploy contract and i have to sendrawtransaction @MikkoOhtamaa